# Visual Studio Code ionic "node_modules" unavailable

Tags: ionic-framework, local-node-modules

I am working on Visual Studio Code. When I look through the list of code the "node_modules, platforms & plugins drop downs" are grey and appear to be unavailable. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: simple code run 'npm i'

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm i` it will regenerate `node_modules`

```
npm install
```

Comment: i gave it a try but did not help

Comment: i dont get an error, just the "node_modules, platforms and plugins" tabs are unavailable, when i click on something inside of those tabs it come up with a problem